# Debug Binary Search Tree in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was trying to create a BST in C. I was just adding bare basic functionalities. However, I have seemed to run into a problem either adding a node or with the in-order traversal - somehow created an infinite loop. Please offer feedback as I am trying to improve. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//node structure 
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
}typedef node;
//create node
node * createLeaf(int x){
    node * temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
//insert node
node *insert(node *root,int x){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = createLeaf(x);
        return root;
    }
    else{
        if(x > root->data){
          root->right = insert(root->right,x);  
       }
        else if(x < root->data){
          root->left = insert(root->left,x);  
       }
    }
    return root;
}
//in-order traversal
void inorder(node * root){
    while(root!=NULL){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d\n",root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
int main()
{
    node * root = NULL;
    root = insert(root,5);
    insert(root,8);
    insert(root,1);
    inorder(root);
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `insert` is lacking the case handling `x == root->data`. Not that it is *the* problem.

Comment: Why are you tagging a question about C with C++?

Comment: You don't need the `while` loop in your `inorder`. Just recursion is sufficient for the full traversal. This is where the infinite loop is - `root` is never update there. Replace `while` with `if`.

Answer (score 1):

What @Eugene suggested replacing while with if will fix the problem
Or you can add a break at the end of while loop and it should also solve your problem.
But I will suggest to only use either recursion or iteration.